# javascript analytics (send variables to php)

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics, statistics, analytics

what does this code do?

( i'm trying to build a web app analytics system, it must send javascript variables too php and then, php add variables to database ...
its a sample code that do this procces. I would like to "know that this code how sends javascript variables to php?" )

```html
(function() {var no=0;var rand=Math.round(Math.random()*50000);var ref = escape(document.referrer) ; var u=(("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https" : "http") + "://analyticstest.com/rx/?xmain2/statsave/9101/50d77b1jkfd24c5db5ef36b22ed8a";
 u = u + "&height=" + screen.height + '&width=' + screen.width +'&now=12552222091&phprand=56bf3sdkjnf220912528&rand='+rand+ '&title=1'  ;
 u = u + "&ref="+ref;
 document.write ("<iframe scrolling=no  frameborder=0 allowtransparency='true' src='"+u+"' border=0 width='0' height='0' style=' display:none;visibility:hidden'></iframe>");
```

Comment: Well if you don't know "what does this code do?" then you need to refresh some basics.

Comment: try to remember this site is for troubleshooting problems, not tutorials